# TextInput keyboard flicker and unselects

Tags: react-native, expo

### The Bug

The issue is when another product appears for a 2nd one to add to the list, when selecting the input(name) the keyboard appears and disappears very quickly, and the input(name) becomes unselected. It is only when I select input(qty) for the 2nd product, they keyboard stays, then I can select the input(name) without the flickering. Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

[image]

**source code:** https://github.com/jamespagedev/react-native-expo-input-handling/tree/problem-second-product-name-input-flicker

## Steps to reproduce error

(note: steps to setup and run project are in the readme of the git repository)

1. Run the project
2. Select any shop and click next
3. In the input(name), type in any name from the products.json file related to the shop you selected. For example, if you selected "Cyber Monkeys", type cat6
4. Unselect the input(name) by clicking anywhere else, and watch the 2nd product form appear below
5. In the 2nd product form, select the input(name) and watch the screen flicker

## The Code

##### Products.tsx

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";
import type { StackNavigationProp } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import type { StackMainParamList } from "@app/navigation/stacks";
import { useOrdersStore } from "@app/stores";
import { BtnMain, MainView } from "@app/components";
import { ProductsList, TopShop } from "./productsChildren";
import { copyByValue, screenNavigations } from "@app/utils";
import { OrderProduct, OrderProductNameValidationStatus } from "@app/types";

const newProduct: OrderProduct = {
  validationNameStatus: "empty",
  name: "",
  qty: "1",
  notes: "",
};

export default function Products(): JSX.Element {
  // variables
  const refIsNextClicked = useRef(false);
  const navigation = useNavigation<StackNavigationProp<StackMainParamList>>();
  const { order, setProducts } = useOrdersStore((store) => store);
  const [tempProducts, setTempProducts] = useState<Array<OrderProduct>>([
    ...order.products,
    copyByValue(newProduct),
  ]);

  // functions
  const unselectNameInput = async (
    text: string,
    index: number,
    status: OrderProductNameValidationStatus
  ) => {
    const updatedProducts: Array<OrderProduct> = copyByValue(tempProducts);
    updatedProducts[index].name = text;
    updatedProducts[index].validationNameStatus = status;
    if (
      status === "success" &&
      updatedProducts[updatedProducts.length - 1].name.length > 0
    ) {
      updatedProducts.push(copyByValue(newProduct));
    }
    setTempProducts(updatedProducts);
  };

  const unselectQtyInput = (text: string, index: number) => {
    const updatedProducts: Array<OrderProduct> = copyByValue(tempProducts);
    updatedProducts[index].qty = text;
    setTempProducts(updatedProducts);
  };

  const removeProduct = (index: number) => {
    setTempProducts(tempProducts.filter((p, i) => i !== index));
  };

  const handleNext = () => {
    const validProducts = tempProducts.filter(
      (p) => p.validationNameStatus === "success"
    );
    if (validProducts.length === 0) return;
    refIsNextClicked.current = true;
    setProducts(validProducts);
  };

  // setup
  useEffect(() => {
    if (order.products.length > 0 && refIsNextClicked.current) {
      navigation.navigate(screenNavigations.review.route as never);
    }
  }, [order.products]);

  // render
  return (
    <MainView>
      <TopShop order={order} />
      <ProductsList
        shopId={order.shop?.id || 1}
        products={tempProducts}
        unselectNameInput={unselectNameInput}
        unselectQtyInput={unselectQtyInput}
        removeProduct={removeProduct}
      />
      <BtnMain name="Next" onPress={handleNext} />
    </MainView>
  );
}
```

##### ProductsList.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import { SafeAreaView, FlatList, StyleSheet, StatusBar } from "react-native";
import { OrderProduct, OrderProductNameValidationStatus } from "@app/types";
import { ProductListItem } from "./productsListChildren";

interface Props {
  shopId: number;
  products: Array<OrderProduct>;
  unselectNameInput: (
    text: string,
    index: number,
    status: OrderProductNameValidationStatus
  ) => Promise<void>;
  unselectQtyInput: (text: string, index: number) => void;
  removeProduct: (index: number) => void;
}

export default function ProductsList(props: Props): JSX.Element {
  const { products } = props;
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        data={products}
        renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
          <ProductListItem {...props} prodIndex={index} product={item} />
        )}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => `${item.name}-${index}`}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: StatusBar.currentHeight || 0,
    padding: 10,
  },
});
```

##### ProductListItem.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import { Pressable, StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import { FontAwesome as Icon } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import { OrderProduct, OrderProductNameValidationStatus } from "@app/types";
import { NameInput, QtyInput } from "./productListItemChildren";

interface Props {
  shopId: number;
  prodIndex: number;
  product: OrderProduct;
  unselectNameInput: (
    text: string,
    index: number,
    status: OrderProductNameValidationStatus
  ) => Promise<void>;
  unselectQtyInput: (text: string, index: number) => void;
  removeProduct: (index: number) => void;
}

export default function ProductListItem({
  shopId,
  prodIndex,
  product,
  unselectNameInput,
  unselectQtyInput,
  removeProduct,
}: Props): JSX.Element {
  return (
    <View style={{ marginBottom: 20, backgroundColor: "#ffffff" }}>
      <View
        style={{
          flexDirection: "row",
          justifyContent: "space-between",
          alignItems: "center",
          padding: 10,
          backgroundColor: "#f8f8f6",
          borderBottomWidth: 1,
          borderBottomColor: "#cccccc",
        }}
      >
        <Text>PRODUCT {prodIndex + 1}</Text>
        {prodIndex !== 0 && (
          <Pressable
            style={styles.closeButton}
            onPress={() => removeProduct(prodIndex)}
          >
            <Icon name="close" size={24} color="#969696" />
          </Pressable>
        )}
      </View>
      <View style={{ paddingHorizontal: 10, paddingTop: 10 }}>
        <View
          style={{
            marginBottom: 10,
            borderBottomWidth: 1,
            borderBottomColor: "#cccccc",
          }}
        >
          <NameInput
            shopId={shopId}
            prodIndex={prodIndex}
            prodName={product.name}
            prodValidation={product.validationNameStatus}
            unselectNameInput={unselectNameInput}
          />
          <QtyInput
            prodIndex={prodIndex}
            prodQty={product.qty}
            unselectQtyInput={unselectQtyInput}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  closeButton: {
    paddingHorizontal: 3,
  },
});
```

##### NameInput.tsx

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { ActivityIndicator, Text, TextInput, View } from "react-native";
import {
  AntDesign as AntIcon,
  MaterialIcons as MatIcon,
} from "@expo/vector-icons";
import { OrderProductNameValidationStatus } from "@app/types";
import { fakeApiValidateProduct } from "@app/apis";

interface Props {
  shopId: number;
  prodIndex: number;
  prodName: string;
  prodValidation: OrderProductNameValidationStatus;
  unselectNameInput: (
    text: string,
    index: number,
    status: OrderProductNameValidationStatus
  ) => Promise<void>;
}

export default function NameInput({
  shopId,
  prodIndex,
  prodName,
  prodValidation,
  unselectNameInput,
}: Props): JSX.Element {
  // variables
  const [name, setName] = useState(prodName);
  const [isNameSelected, setIsNameSelected] = useState(false);
  const [validateNameStatus, setValidateNameStatus] =
    useState<OrderProductNameValidationStatus>(prodValidation);

  // functions
  const handleUnselectNameInput = async (text: string, prodIndex: number) => {
    setIsNameSelected(false);
    if (prodName === name) return;
    if (name.length > 0) {
      setValidateNameStatus("validating");
      const prodValidResponse: boolean = await fakeApiValidateProduct(
        shopId as any,
        name
      );
      if (prodValidResponse) {
        unselectNameInput(text, prodIndex, "success");
      } else {
        unselectNameInput(text, prodIndex, "failed");
      }
    }
  };

  // render
  return (
    <View style={{ position: "relative" }}>
      <Text>Name</Text>
      <TextInput
        style={{
          marginBottom: 10,
          padding: 10,
          borderWidth: 2,
          borderColor: isNameSelected ? "#2ecc71" : "#96a6ad",
          borderRadius: 2,
        }}
        onChangeText={(text: string) => setName(text)}
        onFocus={() => setIsNameSelected(true)}
        onBlur={() => handleUnselectNameInput(name, prodIndex)}
        value={name}
      />
      {validateNameStatus === "success" ? (
        <View style={{ position: "absolute", bottom: 24, right: 10 }}>
          <AntIcon name="checkcircle" size={24} color="#23c0b5" />
        </View>
      ) : validateNameStatus === "failed" ? (
        <View style={{ position: "absolute", bottom: 24, right: 10 }}>
          <MatIcon name="error" size={24} color="#ffa125" />
        </View>
      ) : validateNameStatus === "validating" ? (
        <View style={{ position: "absolute", bottom: 24, right: 10 }}>
          <ActivityIndicator size={25} />
        </View>
      ) : null}
    </View>
  );
}
```

##### QtyInput.tsx

```
import React, { memo, useState } from "react";
import { Text, TextInput, View } from "react-native";

interface Props {
  prodIndex: number;
  prodQty: string;
  unselectQtyInput: (text: string, index: number) => void;
}

function QtyInput({
  prodIndex,
  prodQty,
  unselectQtyInput,
}: Props): JSX.Element {
  // variables
  const [qty, setQty] = useState(prodQty);
  const [isQtySelected, setIsQtySelected] = useState(false);

  // functions
  const handleUnselectedQtyInput = (text: string, prodIndex: number) => {
    if (!/^\d+$/.test(text) && text.length > 0) return; // numbers only
    setIsQtySelected(false);
    const qtyUpdated = text;
    if (qtyUpdated.length === 0) {
      setQty("1");
      unselectQtyInput("1", prodIndex);
    } else {
      unselectQtyInput(qtyUpdated, prodIndex);
    }
  };

  // render
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Qty</Text>
      <TextInput
        style={{
          marginBottom: 10,
          padding: 10,
          borderWidth: 2,
          borderColor: isQtySelected ? "#2ecc71" : "#96a6ad",
          borderRadius: 2,
        }}
        keyboardType="numeric"
        onChangeText={(text: string) => setQty(text)}
        onFocus={() => setIsQtySelected(true)}
        onBlur={() => handleUnselectedQtyInput(qty, prodIndex)}
        value={qty}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

export default memo(QtyInput);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something in the Flatlist in the way it re-renders react is causing the blocking of selecting the 2nd product name input. I found the same issue here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28246

##### The Fix

The fix was just to add this line `removeClippedSubviews={false}`

##### Example: ProductList.tsx Component

```
export default function ProductsList(props: Props): JSX.Element {
  const { products } = props;
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        data={products}
        renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
          <ProductListItem {...props} prodIndex={index} product={item} />
        )}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => `${item.name}-${index}`}
        removeClippedSubviews={false} // <--------------------------- add this line
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```